# SQL Script for synchronizing data between two databases on different servers

Tags: sql-server, database, synchronization

I have two databases with identical structures. I need to write an SQL script that synchronizes data from one database to another. The structure of the database is not very complex, so I decided on a script that will be executed when the need arises.
Databases stand on different servers.
Could you help with writing such a script? E.g. on an example or linking to an article how to do it? I searched the internet and found no helpful articles. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: This will very much depend on what the database is. What is the database?

Comment: Database is MS SQL Server

Comment: This should be a goot starting point: [Synchronize Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/relational-databases/replication/synchronize-data?view=sql-server-ver15). You could also use [triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

The first you want to do is set up a linked server between the two so that one can directly read/write to the other. Then look at the SQL merge command, which should allow you to pretty easily do the sort of sync you are talking about. It doesn't sound like your requirements are too heavy.